# Spring cloud, config server unable to start

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

When I am trying to start SpringBoot main application, getting the below exception. Why am I getting this excpetion.

**Exception:**

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.multipleJGitEnvironmentProperties**
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:193) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:153) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar:5.3.5]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) [spring-boot-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]

**Code:**

**pom.xml**

```
<project>  <!-- Removed name spaces and posted here -->
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.configserver.microservices</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
<description>Centralized configuration server</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

spring.application.name=spring-cloud-config-server 

server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///d:/git-localconfig

#spring.profiles.active=native  (Note: I tried by enabling this property. But not working)

**Spring boot main java class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class SpringCloudConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringCloudConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Try changing the property: `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///d:/git-localconfig` to `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///d:/git-localconfig`
And also add `spring.profiles.active=native`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  No luck. Still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved after making changes to the pom.xml as below

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>2.4.4</version> -->
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version><!-- Working -->
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.configserver.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-cloud-config-server</name>
    <description>Centralized configuration server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version> -->
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version> <!--Working-->
    </properties>
```

Comment: Things have changed in 2.4 and Spring Cloud 2020.x.x releases. If you are migrating from 2.3 > 2.4 and Hoxton.SRX to 2020.x.x please check documentation. There is a compability chart here : https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud